# not an official elementary package

Tags: desktop

I am getting the following error message when I try to report a problem via the about window in Files (same with other default apps)

"The problem cannot be reported:

This is not an official elementary package. Please remove any third party package and try again."

What does this mean?  If I don't have the official package, how did it become unofficial?

Answer (score 1):

check your software ppas with "Software and Updates" utility and make sure you have all the ubuntu ppa's and Elementary's launchpad ppas (aka stable package).

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced this, so it is likely a **bug**. You can track its status at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1634688

Please subscribe to the ticket in case the devs need more information or help testing a fix.