# Installer keeps crashing

Tags: system-installation

I'm having the same problem as this [question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/not-an-official-elementary-package) but am unable to upvote or comment on it; does anyone have a fix or suggestions? I downloaded the OS from the elementary site but the installer keeps crashing (I notice at the `running grub-install /dev/sda` step), and when it tries to collect information to file a report, it tells me that it's not an official elementary package and to remove any third party package.

Comment: At what point is the installer crashing,ie.at boot, during the install process, during the formatting section, or late when installing the grub. Be more specific like post the exact error, if you can't post the error take a photo and upload the image.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the installation worked once I opted to manually choose my partitions and changed the boot loader to my swap partition rather than `/dev/sda`. This seems to be a problem facing Ubuntu users in general: https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub